# Android - difference between static and dynamic button weight

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm working with TableLayout, where the first row is static (XML) and second row is added during the runtime. Both layouts should be visually equal. However, I'm getting different results:

```
ROW 1: [----A-----] [----------B----------] [-----C----]
ROW 2: [-----A-----] [---------B---------] [-----C-----]
```

Here is an XML for ROW 1:

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/stat_A"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:text="A" />
```

The weight is "1" for buttons stat_A and stat_C, and "2" for stat_B.

Here is a Java code for ROW 2:

```
 Button btn = new Button(this);
 btn.setId("dyn_A");
 LayoutParams btn_param = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, _DYN_WEIGHT_);
 btn.setLayoutParams(btn_param);
 btn.setText("A");
 layout.addView(btn);
```

The _DYN_WEIGHT_ is "1" for buttons dyn_A and dyn_C, and "2" for dyn_B.

Where is my mistake?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

The full XML:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Tbl01"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">  

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stat_A"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="A" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stat_B"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="B" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stat_C"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="C" />

    </TableRow>     


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">       
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Post your xml code. The first thing I'm noticing is that you are overwriting the xml layout params of you `Button` in code, `0dp` != `MATCH_PARENT`.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to create all the views by code, you could just inflate an xml file and set the correct values.

Comment: @Mikel aslo populate the header dynamically

Comment: @Steve - is there is a method of defining "0dp" for width via LayoutParams?

Comment: @Pragnani - could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Stephane - unfortunately, I have to manage the whole layout (inc. number of buttons) dynamically.

Comment: @MikelAndropov Populate the above TableRow also Dynamically

Comment: @Pragnani - Populating TableRow dynamically did the job! Thanks a lot! [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8784786/1647407) is a helpful reference.

Comment: @MikelAndropov +1 for your effort in solving your issue by your self